# Checkbox Php : Keep checked only the checked checkbox after submitting Get form

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, checked

This is my code

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat) {  ?>
    <li>
    <input id="category" name="category[]"  type="checkbox" value="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" 
    <?php if (isset($_GET['category'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>><?= $cat->name ?></input>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

But when i submit the form the check boxes are all checked and what i wan't is to keep checked only the checkbox i checked not the others
Example Below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of this line,

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['category'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>> ...
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Upon form submission `$_GET['category']` will be set, hence this condition `isset($_GET['category'])` will hold true for all the checkboxes. And that's why all the checkboxes are checked irrespective of which one you checked earlier. So your `foreach` loop should be like this:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat) {  ?>
    <li>
    <input id="category" name="category[]"  type="checkbox" value="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" 
    <?php if (isset($_GET['category']) && in_array($cat->term_id, $_GET['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>><?= $cat->name ?></input>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Minimal Glad I could help. ;-) By the way, you should get into the habit of *accepting* answers, otherwise the questions will be floating around as *open* questions. Moreover, it'll also encourage other developers to help you further. Please read, [how to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

please take a look on this code , i think it solved your issue.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="small" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['small'])?' checked':'')?> /> Small
<input type="checkbox" name="medium"  class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['medium'])?' checked':'')?> >  Medium<br>
```